# How can I find the code of Smart Contract on a EOS account?

Tags: smart-contract

Maybe a basic question, but how can I find the code of Smart Contract on a EOS account?
For example the code on https://eosflare.io/account/betdicelucky ?

I need this to audit if I can trust the code :-).

If it is NOT possible to check: how can I audit if I can trust a party?

Answer (score 2):

Natively, you may only retrieve the WASM binary that a contract runs, so you can't see the source code.

However, certain block explorers (e.g. [EOSPark](https://eospark.com)) allow smart contract developers to upload the code and verify that it compiles to the same binary, so you can check if the account you're interested in did so or ask if they are willing to do that.

Comment: Absoluteky Correct!    Use - 'cleos get code <eos_account_name>' to find out if an account is a contract one.

Answer (score 0):

In EOSIO you are not able to see code from the account because it is always private no one will show you their code except opensource systems because if they show you the code then their business logic will reveal and everyone will know what's the logic behind that system. User's don't need to audit code because owner's of that system have to audit their smart contract with experts. And there is many companies are there which will audit your contract and provide you certifications for that so, you may ask the party to show you that audit proof if they have audited contract.

Comment: In EOS Constitution, one rule says that Each contract has to be open-source. Currently, a lot of the review systems under development like Referendum. So, once those are ready, then each contract has to upload the code as well in the Block explorers.